# regular expression to leave only first and last character of a string

Tags: regex, postgresql

i'm using a postgres database and I'd like to show certain data leaving just the first and last character of a string (with variable length and containing spaces and special characters); I'd like to replace characters in between with dots '.' or i.e. 'x'
Could you please suggest me the regexp_replace() syntax to use?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing part of the existing string, you could just construct a new one from pieces - the first character, the middle, and the last character.

```sql
SELECT left(str, 1) || repeat('.', length(str) - 2) || right(str, 1);
```

As @kaveh pointed out, that won't work unless the string has at least two characters. This uglier one should work for those cases too:

```sql
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN length(str) > 2 THEN left(str, 1) || repeat('.', length(str) - 2) || right(str, 1) 
  ELSE str END;
```

Comment: You should also handle the case where the string is only one character.

Comment: @kaveh That's a good point, edited.